# How to override "Connection : close" in header Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, http-headers

In my scrapy crawler I have the following custome_settings:

```
 custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            'Connection' : 'Keep-Alive'
        }
    }
```

I have even tried setting the headers in the scrapy.Reqest() as followed:

```
 headers = {}
 headers['Connection'] : 'Keep-Alive'
 headers['User-Agent'] : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'

 for url in urls:
     yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers, callback = self.parse)
```

However the request is not overriding the value. Instead it is just appending another "Connection" into the request header.

Request Packet:

```
GET http://example.com HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Scrapy/1.4.0 (+http://scrapy.org)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

But the request the "Connection : Keep-Alive" is appended to the request headers instead of overriding it. How do I actually override the "Connection" in the header of the request in scrapy?

Comment: What is the reason to do that? Honestly I am not sure if a connection can be kept alive in scrapy and whether it would help or not

Comment: It is causing an error with a website I am trying to scrape. They error out if the connection is aborted too early (i.e "Connection: close")